# Return from react state with date string as key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have defined some dates in my state like so:

```
this.state = {
            dates: [
                {
                    '2020, 4, 1': {
                        morning: {empty: 'no'},
                        afternoon: {}
                    },
                    '2020,6, 1': {
                        morning: {empty: 'no'},
                        afternoon: {}
                    },
                    '2020,7, 1': {
                        morning: {empty: 'no'},
                        afternoon: {}
                    }
                },
            ]
        };
```

As you can see the key for every object is the date itself.

In my function I would like to return these dates but how can I do that properly when I set the date as the key that is not inside the object?

```
getBookedDates(current) {
        let dates = this.state.dates;

        return !dates.some(day => current.isSame(day.date, 'day'));
    }
```

Comment: @GuyIncognito Was a mistake, I corrected it in my code example.

Comment: Looking at the object structure ... you need to loop over the keys of the object ... as in 
`for (var key of Object.keys(dates[0])) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + dates[0][key])
}`

Comment: you can keys of an object using Object.keys(dates[0])

Comment: @SachinKammar I added: let keys = Object.keys(this.state.dates);
        console.log(keys); but it only gets returned like this:  ["0"]

Comment: dates has only one element inside so try this?  let keys = Object.keys(this.state.dates[0]); console.log(keys);

Comment: @SachinKammar That makes sense, however now only the first element (["2020, 4, 1"]) gets returned and the others seem to be ignored

Comment: what does current.isSame(day.date, 'day') do? and what do you want to return from that function?

Comment: @SachinKammar It checks whether or not the objects are the same as the current date and it returns a boolean for that.

Comment: you want to check whether dates array contains current date or not? there are multiple dates, if one of them is same as current date, return true or else false. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @SachinKammar correct

Comment: Try this?
getBookedDates(current) {
        let dates = Object.keys(this.state.dates[0]);
        return dates.some(day => current.isSame(day, 'day'));
  }

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEAQBGNRE9IM

Comment: which one worked for you? I would like to add it as an answer

Comment: @SachinKammar both worked, but in the end I used the first one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for keys try this.

```
getBookedDates(current) { 
  let dates = Object.keys(this.state.dates[0]); 
  return dates.some(day => current.isSame(day, 'day')); 
}
```